# Inserting cookies into WKWebView

Tags: swift, cookies, ios11, wkwebview

I'm having a `webView` inside my app that opens only one website. My problem is: when I want to be logged into the website's services, I have to insert a cookie which can be obtained by a post method with parameters `user` and `pass` that receives whole site's code in html and our cookie in it's header. 
My question is: what will be the best solution for this strange task?
What I have tried is e.g.: Alamofire with post request, `(response as html string)` -> `webView`, `(response.allHeaderFiles)` -> `webView`, but it's not the best solution and it doesn't quite work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let controller = WKUserContentController()
    var source = "" 
    // Pass your cookie
    if let cookies = cookies {
      let cookieSource = cookies.map({"**Add your conditon if any**")
      source += cookieSource
    }
    controller.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: false))
```

Try this.

A **WKUserScript** object represents a script that can be injected into a webpage.

**ForMainFrameOnly** - A Boolean value indicating whether the script should be injected only into the

With the help of **WKUserContentController** you can achieve this.